# How To get Visual Swatch attribute image path in magento2

Tags: magento2

I created one attribute with type Visual Swatch

now i need to get image path of specific option value or product  then how to get it ?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Finaly got it working with below code:

```
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data as SwatchData;
use Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media;

...

public function __construct(
    SwatchData $swatchHelper,
    Media $swatchMediaHelper,
    Config $eavConfig
) {

    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    $this->swatchHelper = $swatchHelper;
    $this->swatchMediaHelper = $swatchMediaHelper;
}

...

$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product',         
$attribute_code); //First get the current attribute
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

//Get all value_id's from attribute and add them to a array
$valueIds = [];

foreach ( $options as $option ) {
    $valueIds[] = $option['value'];
}
//Get all images for value_id's
$images = $this->swatchHelper->getSwatchesByOptionsId($valueIds);
```

Now $images contains an array with the id, label and image for each value.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

```
$swatchHelper=$this->_objectManager->get("Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media");
$swatchCollection = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Swatches\Model\ResourceModel\Swatch\Collection');
// brand logo is my Visual Swatch attribute 
$optionIdvalue=$this->getProduct()->getBrandLogo(); 
$swatchCollection->addFieldtoFilter('option_id',$optionIdvalue);
$item=$swatchCollection->getFirstItem();
echo $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_thumb', $item->getValue());
echo $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_image', $item->getValue());
```

Comment: ObjectManager should not be used like this. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html#usage-rules

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php/***********Display Brand Attribute In Category page************/?>

            <?php
            if($_product->getManufacturer()){
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category

                $brand_value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
                $brand_id = $_product->getManufacturer();
                $curnt_cat_url = $category->getUrl();
                $brandId = '?manufacturer='.$brand_id;

                $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $swatchHelper=$om->get("Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media");
                $swatchCollection = $om->create('Magento\Swatches\Model\ResourceModel\Swatch\Collection');
                $swatchCollection->addFieldtoFilter('option_id',$brand_id);
                $item=$swatchCollection->getFirstItem();
                $ThumbImage =  $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_thumb', $item->getValue());
                $SwatchImage = $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_image', $item->getValue());

                ?>

                <div class="brand_bg">
                    <a href="<?php echo $curnt_cat_url.$brandId ?>"><img src="<?php echo $SwatchImage; ?>"></a>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php/***********End Brand Attribute************/?>
```

Comment: Display Brand image in product page by attribute

Comment: What would be the "option_id" in above code or is it supposed to be as it is?

Comment: "manufacturer"  would be the "option_id" in above code

Comment: ObjectManager should not be used like this. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html#usage-rules

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php/***********Display Brand Attribute************/?>
<?php
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $om->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryHelper = $om->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$categoryRepository = $om->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($catId);
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
?>
<div class="main_brand_bg">
    <ul>
    <?php  
    $brandIds = [];                        
    foreach ($categoryProducts as $_product) {
        if($_product->getManufacturer()){

            $brandValue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
            $brandId = $_product->getManufacturer();
            $curnt_cat_url = $category->getUrl();
            $brandLink = '?manufacturer='.$brandId;

            $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $swatchHelper=$om->get("Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media");
            $swatchCollection = $om->create('Magento\Swatches\Model\ResourceModel\Swatch\Collection');
            $swatchCollection->addFieldtoFilter('option_id',$brandId);
            $item = $swatchCollection->getFirstItem();
            $thumbImage =  $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_thumb', $item->getValue());
            $SwatchImage = $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_image', $item->getValue());

            if (!in_array($brandId,$brandIds )){
                $brandIds[] = $brandId;
            ?>
                <div class="brand_bg">
                    <li class="brand_img_bg"> 
                        <a href="<?php echo $curnt_cat_url.$brandLink; ?>" title="<?php echo $brandValue; ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $thumbImage; ?>"></a>
                    </li>
                </div>

            <?php } ?>

        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ObjectManager should not be used like this. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html#usage-rules

Comment: Object manager used when you did not create a module